# Word for not being able to focus on one task

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, hebrew

In Hebrew, my native language, we have a word describing the inability of one to focus on a certain task and instead thinking or doing one or many related/unrelated things. This word roughly translates to "being scattered" or "being dispersed". Are there any other more appropriate words to describe such thing?

Note: if this word can be used in the context of not speaking to the point during a conversation it also fits the usage of the Hebrew one.

Comment: As a father, I would have to say Teenagerness :-)

Comment: How about seeing ghosts? Taking paths which seem like invisible leaps to others because they don't see them.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The word closest to the examples you already gave is [**scatterbrained**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatterbrained):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : having or showing a forgetful, disorganized, or unfocused mind : having the characteristics of a scatterbrain

Comment: I like this answer more than any other here. While other answers are talking about the manifestation, this answer is closer to describing the cause of the manifestation.

Answer (score 21):

"Distracted" is the word you are looking for, where you are not concentrated. That's when while doing one task your mind reacts to what your eyes are watching and what you are thinking, you get drawn away from your task, and you get distracted by other things.

Comment: Yes. I sometimes have difficulty focusing, and it's that focused/distracted dichotomy (or continuum) that comes into play.

Answer (score 11):

**scattered**

I can't find a good dictionary definition of this, but this book title shows pretty clearly how it can be used for your concept:

> [Smart but Scattered: The Revolutionary "Executive Skills" Approach to Helping Kids Reach Their Potential](http://Smart%20but%20Scattered:%20The%20Revolutionary%20%22Executive%20Skills%22%20Approach%20to%20Helping%20Kids%20Reach%20Their%20PotentialJan%202,%202009)

**all over the place**

This phrase works great for the context you're interested in.  Example:

> John's comments included some interesting points, but he was **all over the place** and in the end he didn't help our case.  I think we should leave him off the speaker list for next time.

Finally, the most obvious word:

**unfocused**

(needs no explanation; usage: the same as "all over the place")

---

**Edit** (4/23): There is another one gaining traction in the US at least:

**ADHD** (as an adjective)

This is an acronym for a neurodevelopmental diagnosis, Attention Deficit/Hyperactivity Disorder, which is a subtype of ADD, Attention Deficit Disorder.  Example showing how it's starting to be used in the US:

> Prof. X is a good teacher but if you want to get questions answered in office hours, make sure you bring a written list of your questions with you.  Keep coming back to your list if he goes off on ADHD tangents.

Be careful with this one.  It hasn't lost the stigma everywhere yet.

Comment: I like the *all over the place* phrase; seems very apt here.

Comment: @k1eran - Well, I have such a person in my family and have experience explaining his nature to people.  Usually I say that he's wired differently than the bell curve.  But there are lots of pluses.

Comment: "It hasn't lost the stigma everywhere yet." You expect it to?

Comment: @Beanluc - Maybe not *expect*, but *hope* -- yes, definitely, why not?  Look what Tim Howard has done to destigmatize Tourette Syndrome.

Comment: You weren't talking about destigmatizing the condition, you were talking about destigmatizing the abuse of the condition's name. Calling someone Tourette's doesn't destigmatize the condition, I'd tend to think it does the complete opposite.

Comment: @Beanluc - Let me just check something I'm not sure if I'm understanding.  Do you feel that "Keep coming back to your list if he goes off on ADHD tangents" is offensive to people with ADHD?

Comment: Them and others, yes, that's exactly where I'm coming from.

Comment: @Beanluc - Can you think of an example informal sentence where ADHD could be used without offense?  (Other than the trivial cases such as "X has been diagnosed with ADHD," "Due to his ADHD, Y gets distracted easily.")

Comment: The only one I can think of would be a "take back the word" type of situation, where a member of this group uses it in their own way for their own communications. Appropriating it and labeling distracted people with it doesn't destigmatize anything and is insensitive on many levels.

Comment: @Beanluc - This is helpful feedback. My own experience is that if someone calls my son hyperactive, I feel offended.  But I have heard and used ADHD in sentences that didn't strike me as offensive.  The thing is, Tourette trumps ADHD, and Tourette can be extremely embarrassing.  Honesty and humor are what keeps us going.

Answer (score 3):

The person is:

- absentminded;
- inattentive;
- miles away (informal);
- in a world of his/her own (informal); and,
- (maybe) daydreaming.

I like the above suggestions better, even though, per any dictionary, these all are synonyms of 'distracted' which already exists as an answer in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

to **wander** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wander)

> (of the mind, thoughts, etc) to lose concentration or direction

As in:

> He frequently wandered off the point during our conversation.

Answer (score 0):

As to the sense of "not speaking to the point during a conversation", you could say **prevaricate**, or more informally "beating around the bush", but these don't extend to the other sense you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> **Distractible**
>   (also distractable)
>      Easily distracted.

[(Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/distractible).

in fact *easily-distracted* is useful in its own right.